# var Keywords-Javascript: How it is possible?

Tags: javascript

**How a system reads this. Unable to find the Logic behind ?**

```js
var x;
x=10;
x=20;
x=x+x;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: *"Unable to find the Logic behind"* Really? Because you can't swing a dead cat on the 'net without finding explanations of how `var` works; the rest is basic assignment and addition. My own meager attempt (for `var`): http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html

Comment: This post has made me curious --  what were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 3):

```
var x, x, x; //declare x 3 times (it makes no sense for me but javascript allows it)
x = 10; // x now is 10
x = 20; // x now is 20
x = x + x; // x now is (x + x) = (20 + 20) = 40
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x; //print 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is interpreted:

```
var x; // excedentary symbol declaration have no effect
x = 10; // value assigned to symbol x
x = 20; // value assigned to symbol x, effectively overwriting previous value
x = x + x; // 20 + 20 = 40
```

Comment: x is a not `symbol` its `variable name`

Comment: Yeah I know, using symbol for "item in the variable object" is a bit confusing now that es6 has introduced a Symbol object...

Answer (score 1):

**its last value assing to variable in same scope with same name define by us**

like you define `x = 30;` than it `assing 30 to x` and after that `x value for all is 30` so no need to create `var x,x,x`

```js
var x, x, x;
x = 10;
x = 20;
x = 30;
x = x + x;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x;
  x = 10; // Here x = 10
  x = 30; // Here x = 30
  x = x + x; // Now we have 'x=30' from line(2); x=(30 + 30 = 60                      is the answer)
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```